# Authorization in OpenLiberty using Custom Identity Store

Tags: java, security, web-applications, authorization, open-liberty

I am trying to build a web application using primefaces and OpenLiberty. I built a custom identity store which authenticates the password and also returns the groups associated with the user.
I am however, unable to understand how do I map these groups so that when I configure a security-constraint in web.xml with a certain URL pattern, it is able to authorize the user.
This is what I am returning from my custom identity store - [image]

If I put in a security-constraint in web.xml now with the group returned above, it again prompts me for a username and password. I think somehow, the server is unable to determine that I already have the group information and the user is authenticated. How do I configure this?
I am a newbie in this and would appreciate some help.